# SVG with CSS Animation lag on Firefox. Improvement needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

i created my first SVG with the following Code.

```css
.line {
            stroke-dasharray: 1000;
            opacity: 0.7;
            stroke: #000000;

        }

        .animation {
            animation: cons_anim 3s infinite steps(260);
            stroke-dasharray: 4 12 4 12 4 100;
            stroke-linecap: round;
            stroke: #FFFFFF;
        }

        .path {
            fill: none;
        }

        @keyframes cons_anim {
            0% {
                stroke-dashoffset: 250;
            }

            100% {
                stroke-dashoffset: -22;
            }
        }
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 510 510" width="510" height="510" class="" id="svg_image">
        <defs>
            <!-- Pathes -->
            <path id="solar_to_battery" d="M 230,88 v 142 l 0,0 h -142" class="path" />
            <path id="solar_to_grid" d="M 250,88 v 324" class="path" />
            <path id="solar_to_house" d="M 270,88 v 142 l 0,0 h 142" class="path" />
            <path id="house_to_car" d="M 448,286 v 124" class="path" />
            <path id="grid_to_house" d="M 270,412 v -142 l 0,0 h 142" class="path" />
            <path id="grid_to_battery" d="M 230,412 v -142 l 0,0 h -142" class="path" />
            <path id="battery_to_house" d="M 88,250 h 324" class="path" />
            <path id="house_to_custom" d="M 448,210 v -120" class="path" />
        </defs>
        <!-- Lines -->
        <use class="line all_elm" xlink:href="#solar_to_battery" id="line_solar_to_battery" />
        <use class="line all_elm" xlink:href="#solar_to_grid" id="line_solar_to_grid" />
        <use class="line all_elm" xlink:href="#solar_to_house" id="line_solar_to_house" />
        <use class="line all_elm" xlink:href="#house_to_car" id="line_house_to_car" />
        <use class="line all_elm" xlink:href="#grid_to_house" id="line_grid_to_house" />
        <use class="line all_elm" xlink:href="#grid_to_battery" id="line_grid_to_battery" />
        <use class="line all_elm" xlink:href="#battery_to_house" id="line_battery_to_house" />
        <use class="line all_elm" xlink:href="#house_to_custom" id="line_house_to_custom" />

        <!-- Animation -->
        <use class="all_elm animation" xlink:href="#solar_to_house" id="anim_solar_to_house" />
        <use class="all_elm animation" xlink:href="#grid_to_house" id="anim_grid_to_house" />
        <use class="all_elm animation" xlink:href="#solar_to_grid" id="anim_solar_to_grid" />
        <use class="all_elm animation" xlink:href="#house_to_car" id="anim_house_to_car" />
        <use class="all_elm animation" xlink:href="#grid_to_battery" id="anim_grid_to_battery" />
        <use class="all_elm animation" xlink:href="#solar_to_battery" id="anim_solar_to_battery" />
        <use class="all_elm animation" xlink:href="#battery_to_house" id="anim_battery_to_house" />
        <use class="all_elm animation" xlink:href="#house_to_custom" id="anim_house_to_custom" />
    </svg>
```

It runs ok with one line, but when i add (like so) more than 3 or 4 of them, Firefox starts lagging around.
Could someone please help me, to improve this?

Perhaps with Javascript? I am open to any suggestions.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "add more than 3 of them"? Could you please show the code as it is when it's not behaving as intended?

Comment: As you can see, there is one line animating. When I add 3 of them, Firefox lags.

Comment: Yes I can see that there is one line, what I need to see though is how you did "add 3 of them". We need to see exactly what you did, there are several ways of doing this.

Comment: When you enhance your question; please use that [<>] button in the editor, and make your code an executable snippet. Also makes it easier for us to copy your code with one click, tnx

Comment: @Kaiido I entered the code. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Thanks a lot for telling me the Code Snippet. I didnt see that.

Comment: Can't see no lag in my Firefox 103.0.1 on macOS.

Comment: @Kaiido Ok, but i have the lags in my FF on Windows. Could you perhaps let me know, if i could improve some optimizations to the animation? I suppose, its consuming much CPU and therefore it lags. If i only open the animation, FF is using more than 50% of CPU - if i hide it, it consumes only 10-15%. Only 35% of power are used to animate it.